# Xpath works on "MSXML2.DOMDocument" but not on "MSXML2.DOMDocument60"

Tags: xml, vba, xpath, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String greater, less, and equal comparison in XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466494/string-greater-less-and-equal-comparison-in-xmldocument)

Hi,
In VBA I have the folowing expression:

```
 SourceXml.selectNodes("//Races/Race[/FirstRun[@ActStart>'2011-03-01' or
 @ActEnd<'2011-03-15']]")
```

If I define the SourceXml as MSXML2.DOMDocument it retrieves a list with the desired nodes.
If I define the SourceXml as MSXML2.DOMDocument60 it retrieves a list with 0 elements inside.

Whath is wrong with the Xpath expression?

Comment: First, you test an attribute and then an element. Strange... But the main problem is that `>` and `<` comparison operators are defined only for numbers: from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans *When neither object to be compared is a node-set and the operator is `<=`, `<`, `>=` or `>`, then the objects are compared by converting both objects to numbers and comparing the numbers according to IEEE 754* . This is a duplicate, but I'm laizy today...

Comment: I've found the duplicate [String greater, less, and equal comparison in XmlDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466494/string-greater-less-and-equal-comparison-in-xmldocument)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of the problem and for a suggested solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The expression you have provided**:

```
//Races/Race[/FirstRun[@ActStart>'2011-03-01' or  ActEnd<'2011-03-15']]
```

**will not select any node**, because in XPath 1.0 there are no `>` or `<` comparison operators for strings (only for numbers). The two strings above are first converted to numbers, which yields `NaN` and any comparison involving `NaN` is `false()`. Therefore, the value of the predicate is `false()` and the expression doesn't select any node.

**The fact that using `MSXML2.DOMDocument.SelectNodes()` selects nodes is because in this early version of MSXML the default selection language is not XPath** but something called "XSL" (if I remember well) and it is not the standard, W3C XPath language.

I guess that MSXML6 no longer provides this obsolete dialect.

**In your case you might be able to use this XPath expression successfully**:

```
//Races/Race[/FirstRun
              [translate(@ActStart,'-','') > 20110301 
             or
               translate(ActEnd, '-','') < 20110315
              ]
            ]
```

Comment: Just a question more; is "translate" part of Xpath or from DomDocument?

Comment: @CaBieberach: Yes, `translate()` is a standard XPath function.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, `MSXML2.DOMDocument` is the equivalent of `MSXML2.DOMDocument30` - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx DOMDocument30 used XSLPattern as the default selection language (but this can be changed to XPath via the SelectionLanguage 2nd level property - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)