# VBA:Use of UCase builtin property

Tags: excel, vba

I was stuckup using UCase in my following line of code ->
  //xmlTag1doc is having a xml

```
    Dim xmlTag1doc As IXMLDOMElement,Dim ParentDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    set xmlTag1Doc = ParentDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Root//XP")

   if(xmlTag1Doc .SelectNodes("//tag1[@ID = 1 and @Name='" & strname & "']").Length >0)
```

Here I have to use "UCase" to check like UCase(@Name) = UCase(strname) in my line of code.
Is it possible?
Suggest some answers please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be better if you rename `xmlDoc` with something more appropriate like `xmlTag1Elements`. So you will immediatelly know what data is contained in that variable.

Comment: @CaBieberach:Thanks for the answer.It worked.Just two more questions i`ll ask please answer.Why did I use MSXML2.DOMDocument40 and what translate function does actually??

Comment: @CaBieberach: Got the answer sir.Thanks a lot.It works in all way.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with "does not work". Give more details about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
if(xmldoc.SelectNodes("//tag1[translate(@Name,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') = '" & strings.UCase(strname) & "']").Length >0)
```

**EDIT:**

In this case dimention `ParantXMLDoc as MSMXL2.DOMDocumentXX`. (Where ***XX*** is any version equal or higher 40).  As xmlDoc is a node from the ParantXMLDoc, then it will be the same type of DOM version as the ParentXMLDoc.

**Why DOMDocument40 or highet?**
Because version 4.0 is the first DOM version that fully supports XPath 1.0.  Before that version not every Xpath 1.0 function was supported.  For example Translate()

**Translate(*String1*,*findString*,*replaceString*)** 
This function searches the *String1* and replace any *findString* with the *replaceString*. 
On the w3org site you can get more info.  Check the link: [Xpath - w3Org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)

---

Be carefull:

Because you are using `//` in this Xpath `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//tag1[@Name='" & strname & "']")` you are querying ALL `tag1` elements inside `ParentXMLDoc`.  Not just inside the pre selected elements in `xmlDoc`.

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.I`m getting error on "translate" function like "Err Source:msxml3.dll Errdesc :Unknown method.".

Comment: You shoud declare `xmldoc as MSXML2.DOMDocument40` or greater.  Before that version instead of full Xpath, it was an own query language supported.  See Dimitre's answer in this post for more info on that. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865476/xpath-works-on-msxml2-domdocument-but-not-on-msxml2-domdocument60)

Comment: I have put changed my post.please check.I have put more code.